# What does _Default keyword mean in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, classname

For example, I have created a webpage and it has _Default keyword in it.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
```

What does that keyword do in here? What is the point ?

Comment: It is not a keyword (btw, all C# keywords are lower-cased), it's just a class name

Answer (score 15, accepted):

_Default isn't a keyword, it's your class name.

Comment: Then why is it coloured ? What is the special thing about it ?

Comment: it's just a setting of your IDE (eg. visual studio) (color of classNames)

Comment: I can't comment for web development directly, but my class names always appear colored once they are resolved correctly by Intellisense.

Comment: Andreas had a better answer, you can just change it even if you really want to.

Answer (score 5):

default is a keyword used in the C# switch statement, and in VB.Net applies to a default property. That's why the IDE renamed your class _Default, based on the name of the page (Default.aspx). _Default is in itself not a keyword, and appears to be colored differently because every other word on that line *is* a keyword.

Comment: True, but completely out of context with this question

Comment: @Keith - I added a short comment, then edited to expand (while you commented). Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: out of context. missing `default()`, just to be complete!

Answer (score 1):

It is not a keyword, that is the name of the class. Variable names can start with a-z, A-Z, and '_'.

Answer (score 1):

keyword names are lowercase. this is your class name. if your page name is default, asp.net get this name to it's class.